# Python 'FATAL ERROR' on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.5, fatal-error

I installed Python 3.5 previously in my PC. But somehow, maybe a Windows 10 update messed up my Python installation. Can you solve this?

Here's my python info:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python --version
Python 3.5.4

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00002c30 (most recent call first):

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set | findstr /i python

Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\rodrigo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\rodrigo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;C:\Users\rodrigo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\snap\bin
PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin;C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32
```

Comment: What are you doing to get this error? It's jumping between 2.7 and 3.5

Comment: Can't you just reinstall it?

Comment: Your `PYTHONPATH` is wrong, and it's what's prepending 2.7 directories to `sys.path`. Remove it entirely. It's meant for your development libraries (but using virtual environments is better). If pywin or pywin32_system32 need help getting in `sys.path`, there are proper ways to do this that are local to an installation, such as .pth files. Also, remove `PYTHONHOME` if you defined it.

Comment: Can you try this in CMD `python  -c "import sys; print(sys.path);"`